# proc means print conditional stats

Tags: sas

I have several vars, for which there are different score scales.
I can ran 'proc means' and according to the MIN and MAX decide if there are errors in my data.
how do I put a condition for a parameter in the proc means step?
for example;
if my min value for var X is below 1 and max is above below 1 or above 5
and if my min value for var Y is below 0 or above 1 =>
 then I want it to print it out

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how dynamic you need your conditions to be but if you want to see the full summary statistics of subgroups (eg by `sex` and `age` in below example) which breach certain conditions in the summary statistics (eg `weight` and `height` in below example) then you you could do the following:

```
* Generate summary statistics dataset ;
proc summary data=sashelp.class nway ;
  class sex age ;
  var weight height ;
  output out=sumstats;
run ;

* Subset previous dataset to only cases where conditions are met ;
* Height <= 55 ;
* Weight >= 100 ;
proc sql ;
create table subset as
  select a.*
  from sumstats as a
  right join
  (select sex, age 
   from sumstats
   /**** Define summary stat criteria here ****/
   where (_stat_='MIN' and height le 55) 
      or (_stat_='MAX' and weight ge 100)) as b
   on a.sex=b.sex
   and a.age=b.age
;quit ;
```

This final subset dataset includes the full summary statistics for only the subgroups that meet all the defined criteria

Comment: I need to do this in a different way than sql. suppose I detected the vars I needed, I want to print out the id for the following conditions, but it gives me error regarding the "where" clause, is it possible to do this  with a proc print step and "where" statement =>                               proc print data=comb;
var id;
 where q3 not in (1,2,3,4,5);
 where q2 not in (1,2,3,4,5);
 where q10 not in (1,2,3,4,5);
where gender not in (0,1);
where married not in (0,1);
run ;